# Android: Activity restarted when turn off wifi in setting

Tags: android, restart

I have added android:configChanges in Manifest, when I change font size or turn off Wifi, the activity will be restarted automatically. Is there any way I can prevent this restarts ?

Thanks for the help.

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/SkoletubeTheme"
                android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Are you sure it gets restarted due to configuration change? Is it foreground while wifi is turned off?

Comment: it's background while wifi turn off

Comment: Well, then maybe it goes through normal activity lifecycle when it is destroyed and then recreated.

Comment: from this document, seems it can prevent the restarting behavour once the setting is changed. but seems doesn't work for my app.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 1):

You have already caught the exception. It's happen for `android:configChanges` . Please remove unnecessary values from `android:configChanges`. Only keeps `orientation` .

I think your problem will be solved. Try this and let me know if it's acceptable or not.

Comment: seems it doesn't work, it still restart the activity when using just orientation.

Comment: if you need to change orientation then do some code for orientation otherwise keep your only in single orientation.